# Unable to boot any Ubuntu based distro, Is it my motherboard?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I've used Linux before and was a big fan. switchbacked to windows for a little bit (5 months) and realized that I wanted to go back :). Sadly every distro I've tried (outside of fedora strangely) have never booted past the grub screen. I understand if you have heard this question before but I have just never found a way that works for me :(. I've tried installing in both with UEFI on and off, along with reinstalling grub, changing bios settings and even changing hard drive with no success :(. if anyone could help me find out what is going on, I would forever be grateful!

edit: I understand if you may be confused on why if I could boot into fedora just fine why wouldn't just use it. simple just didn't like it as much as my xubuntu and ubuntu

Comment: Please describe the computer/motherboard: Brand name and model, graphics chip/card, wifi chip/card, RAM (size). Please describe also which Ubuntu version you have tried, and which tool you used to make a boot drive (DVD disk or USB pendrive).

Comment: The computer is a gateway dx4870 with a Gtx 960 put in :). I've tried Ubuntu 17.04, Xubuntu 16.04, and Lubuntu 17.04. The tools I used to make the boot drive is Etcher and Unetbootin. i used a USB pendrive

Comment: Are these data matching your computer (except the graphics card)? https://www.cnet.com/products/gateway-dx4870-ub308-core-i3-2130-3-4-ghz-6-gb-1-tb/specs/ - How much RAM? -- You could try with the boot option `nomodeset` (I think there are problems because of the graphics, and I would suggest that you try Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS  download via this link, http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.1/release/

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am having the trouble with. the amount of ram is 16gb of ddr3. for the boot option, i have tried nomodeset and it seems to not make a difference and that is what caused me to think it was a motherboard issue. I will try the Lubuntu 16.04.1 you suggest :)

Comment: If this is still there: "Graphics Controller - Form Factor:  integrated; Graphics Processor: Intel HD Graphics 2000; Video Interfaces: HDMI, VGA" you could connect the monitor to the Intel graphics and try if that will be more successful. - Etcher has a good reputation. Rufus in another good tool in Windows for making USB boot drives. - Check with md5sum, that the downloaded iso files are good.

Comment: I am back with the news.So far I have tried Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and it has the same problem like the others.Taking out the 960 did seem to kind of work. As in it booted but it is too slow for my work even with updating the drivers (which then made it somewhat unstable)

Comment: I have not much to add. Maybe it will work better with Lubuntu or Xubuntu version 17.10, that will be released during this month (October 2017). The new version comes with a new linux kernel, and the new linux kernel comes with new hardware drivers.

Comment: 16.04.1 uses the same kernel series as 16.04 GA, so 16.04.1 isn't likely to fix kernel or driver-related problems with 16.04 GA. The current version in the xenial series is 16.04.3, which uses the same kernel as 17.04 (namely, Linux 4.10). Thus, I recommend you try 16.04.3, 17.04, or the RC of 17.10. (See [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/HEADER.html) for the latest daily build.)